# Refactoring - See if record exists then get record

Tags: c#, refactoring, database-connection

I am trying to avoid two calls to the database.
I need to check if a record exists, if so then fill my view with the data.
I have the following code:

```
        if (Presenters.PayeePresenter.GetByID(id) != null)
        {
            view = BLL.Presenters.PayeePresenter.GetByID(id);

            msg.Success = true;
            msg.Text = "Record Found";
        }
```

How can I just do minimal amount of calls to the database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store result in variable and check whether its null before assigning properties.

```
var obj = Presenters.PayeePresenter.GetByID(id); //Assuming this is database method call
if (obj!= null)
{
   //use obj.Properties to fill custom object or any additional logic
   msg.Success = true;
   msg.Text = "Record Found";
}
```

Comment: Introduce variable refactoring.